# caret rpart decision tree plotting result

Tags: r, decision-tree, r-caret, rpart

I am training a decision tree model based on the heart disease data from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/ronitf/heart-disease-uci).

Since I am also building other models using 10-fold CV, I am trying to use caret package with rpart method to build the tree. However, the plot result is weird as "thalium" should be a factor. Why does it show "thaliumnormal <0.5"? Does this mean that if "thalium" == normal" then take the left route "yes", otherwise right route "no"?

Many thanks!

[image: caret rpart decision tree plot using fancyRpartPlot]

Edits: I apologize for not providing enough background info, which seemed to cause some confusion. "thalium" is a variable that represents a technique used to detect coronary stenosis (aka narrowing). It's a factor with three levels (normal, fixed defect, reversible defect).

[image: data structure]

In addition, I would like to make the graph more readable e.g. instead of "thaliumnormal < 0.5", it should be something like "thalium = normal". I could achieve this goal through using rpart directly (see below).

[image: rpart decision tree plot]

However, you probably have noticed that the tree is different, despite I used the recommended cp value with caret rpart CV 10 folds (see the code below).

[image: code]
[image: recommended cp, used for rpart tree using fancyRpartplot]

I understand that these two packages may result in some differences. Ideally, I could use caret with method rpart to build the tree so that it aligns with other models built in caret. Does anyone know how I could make the plot label for the tree model built with caret rpart easier to understand?

Answer (score 5):

It would help if there were some data, like `dput(head(data))` to show us what your data really looks like or a `str(data)` to show the levels of variables and data types.

But likely (without having seen it) the variable is `thallium` and one level is `normal` and the table has selected a LEVEL of the variable `thallium` and is evaluating, if something is that level `normal` or not.

The tree treats categorical variables as dummies by level and makes a decision based on being >= .5 or < .5 and 0 is always less and 1 is always more.

By design most tree algorithms choose the cut-off for each of the variables (including a dummy 0./1) that creates the most purity (moves the most observations to one side or another and closer to classification) and picks a point midway between the two values which create the greatest separation in groups.

With a binary variable, that split is at .5 because it is midway between the two different values a level can take 0 and 1.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I thought :) By any chance, do you know how to make the plot result more friendly? (see the edited post for more details)

Comment: I do not really. I have resorted to using these types in my personal reports for interpretation and tuning, and if something is needed for stakeholders, to manually create more user-friendly sections of the trees with human-optimized labeling and better color schemes for presentations....

Answer (score 0):

Your factor `thaliumnormal` is either 0 or 1, which represent yes or no - correct?

In that case, `rpart` takes the midvalue 0.5 so that all decision of `0` or `1` is either above or below `0.5`.

Values below the cut-off, in this case 0.5, always turns left. So  `thaliumnormal==0` turns left, yes.

You can see the same example as for `sex`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. thalium is a factor, "normal" is one of the levels (3 in total). I think caret automatically does one hot coding conversion and hence glues the original variable name with each level.